# [Qt]Крашится приложение при вводе текста в TextField

Tags: qt, qt5, qml, jtextfield

При попытке ввода текста в textField из QtQuick 2.9 крашится приложение. Для этого достаточно ввести любой символ. Код:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    TextField {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        placeholderText: qsTr("Login")
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

В **project.pro**:

```
QT += qml quick core
CONFIG += c++11

TEMPLATE = app
```

Вывод приложения: "qt.winrtrunner.app: Failed to show input panel. (???????? ??????? ?????????.)"

Comment: А если версию Controls поменять на 2.4, или пониже?

Comment: Пробовал с версиями 2.0 - 2.5, вывод приложения: "qt.winrtrunner.app: Failed to show input panel. (???????? ??????? ?????????.)"

Comment: А если версию QtQuick  поменять?

Comment: Windows 10 x64, Mingw64 Qt 5.12.1 работает.

Comment: а вы Mingw64  вместе с QtCreator ставили? Нужен ли QtWebEngine?

Comment: Да вместе. При установке выделял только компилятор (вот как раз этот MinGW64), все остальное оставил по-умолчанию

Answer (score 1):

В настройках проекта забыл добавить Mingw64